# Why connection string is necessary to keep in main web app and in data access project in asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a N-Tier ASP.Net MVC application where I am having a Data access layer in which I have stored connection string in App.config file.
I have another project as web application where I am using services to fetch records from database, when I run the web application I got the error of connection string to resolve that I put connection string in web.config file.
I am confused, Why it is necessary to have connection string at multiple places (Web project and Data access layer project)

Comment: I think when the web application is loaded, only the web.config would be loaded and the connection string in that would be required. Have you tried with connection string in only web app and not in data access layer?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common misconception. Configuration belongs to the application. When your app is compiled/published, the DAL gets rolled in as a DLL. Any config you had in that particular project does not apply. The only thing that matters is the config in the project that's actually deployed. In truth, if you've got something like a class library, then having an `App.config` or whatever is basically pointless, anyways. It's never going to be used.

Just put your connection string in your Web.config.

Comment: There are *some* cases where the web.config can be useful for a DLL, but they all involve pre-compile stage things like the IDE,  Tools, and Designers. As you said, it should have no effect on the compiled output though.